# How to integrate Google Reader in my android application

Tags: android, google-reader

I want to integrate Google Reader in my android application. What is the related API.  Please help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Reader is available as a Java Script, it needs to be evaluated when any page is loaded. The logic in the JS will get the article and modifies the original content. The JS can be evaluated by loadurl method. Hope this is useful